# websphere work manager work timeout

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, workmanagers

From the official documentation for work manager's work timeout

> Specifies the number of milliseconds to wait before attempting to release a unit of work. The timeout interval begins when the unit of work starts, rather than when the unit of work is submitted.

[image]

I set the work timeout to 1000 milliseconds and made sure that my thread is engaged for more than that time by calling `Thread.sleep(10000)`. Still nothing happened or no exception was thrown. The thread was engaged for the sleep duration and was returned to pool only after that for other requests.

What does `work object is released means then`?

Comment: Work request queue full action is block, could you change to fail, what will be result ?

Comment: On setting it to fail.. An exception is thrown when request queue is full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method on the `com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.Work` interface named `release`.  This documentation is literally referring to the work manager invoking that method on your `Work` implementation in response to the work timeout being reached.  You can implement your `release` to do whatever you like, for example invoking `yourWorkThread.interrupt()` or setting some flag to indicate to the work that it should stop continuing to do new work.

Here is a link to the Work API JavaDoc:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/asynchbeans/Work.html?view=kc#release()